# SQL Exception in run time

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to add values to a database using WPF form.

This is my code:

```
private void Insertbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-HSIK0SQ; Initial Catalog=Demo; Integrated Security=SSPI");
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Student VALUES ("+ RollNumebrtxt + "," + FNametxt + "," + Coursetxt + ")";
    
    int count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    MessageBox.Show(count + " record saved successfully");

    conn.Close();
}
```

When I am hitting the insert button:

[image: WPF form]

This is the exception being thrown:

[image: Exception]

I am sure that whichever the labels and text boxes I have added they have unique name in the property. It is throwing exception while executing the query command

I am not sure what I could miss here?

Comment: **Parametrise** your code. Your application is wide upon to injection attacks and writing good, secure code will also solve the problem you are encountering.

Comment: This is just for practice.. do yo solution for the problem I stated?

Comment: [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements)

Comment: I understand that but, is that the solution to above problem?

Comment: Yes, the solutions is to use parameters, **always**. Side note: your connection and command objects need `using` to dispose them

Comment: As I said, writing good, secure code will resolve the problem too. If you *parametrise* your code you won't get the SQL syntax error you are getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to surround these values with single quotes `''`, and if these variables are the TextBoxes, then you have to call `.Text` on them to get the proper values..

```
cmd.CommandText = "Insert into Student values ('"+ RollNumebrtxt.Text + "','" + FNametxt.Text + "','" +
        Coursetxt.Text + "');";
```

---

**Better to parametrised your query..**

Replace

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Student VALUES ("+ RollNumebrtxt + "," + FNametxt + "," + Coursetxt + ")";
```

With

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Student VALUES(@RollNumber, @FName, @CourseName)", conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@RollNumber", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(RollNumebrtxt.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@FName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = FNametxt.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@CourseName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = Coursetxt.Text;
```

Comment: And when someone inevitably has an apostrophe in their name?

Comment: Or, what about when someone enters their course as `Maths'); DROP TABLE Student;--` or [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) enrolls?

Comment: @Larnu that will throw a run time exception

Comment: Even for practice this is wrong. Use parameters, it's not difficult

Comment: @Mr.A I've updated the answer, better to use the parametrised version..

Comment: *"that will throw a run time exception"* no, no it wouldn't @MuhammadSulaiman .

Comment: @Larnu wrong mention :)

Comment: @MuhammadSulaiman why use of parameters is recommended? how use of parameters makes code safe?

Comment: Have you read the question I linked @Mr.A ? You wouldn't be asking that if you did.

Comment: See the example Larnu has posted of using `Maths'); DROP TABLE Student;` in some of the fields.. the simicolon `;` will end the query and starts another query that can drop tables from db and that will cause damage to your application/system